# Which provider should I use with `qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer` method at `PostgreSQL database with PostGIS extension` storage?

Tags: postgis, layers, qgis-3, database, pyqgis-3

I use `PyQGIS 3.6.1 Noosa` to load layer from my database storage `PostgreSQL database with PostGIS extension` using `qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer` method. But layer is invalid somehow. Performing same operation with QGIS interface - successfully creates the layer (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnoGp.png)).

**How to create a layer with `qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer` method?**

Here is part of my code:

```py
def load_layer_from_DB(aSchema, aTable, aGeometryColumn, host, port, dbname, user, password):
    uri = qgis.core.QgsDataSourceUri()
    uri.setConnection(host, port, dbname, user, password)
    uri.setDataSource(aSchema, aTable, aGeometryColumn)    
    layer = qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'some_name', "postgis") # i have tried `postgres`, `postgresql` but no luck

# connect stuff
dbname = 'db_visdata'
host = 'ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх'
port = 'хххх'
user = 'хххххххххх'
password = 'хххххххххх'

# path in database
aSchema = "test_data"
aTable = 'test_satellite_boarders'
aGeometryColumn = 'MultiPolygon'

layer = load_layer_from_DB(aSchema, aTable, aGeometryColumn, host, port, dbname, user, password)

print('layer.isValid=', layer.isValid())
print('layer.type=', layer.type())
print('layer.name=', layer.name())
print('layer.featureCount=', layer.featureCount())
return layer
```

Output:

```
layer.isValid= False
layer.type= 0
layer.name= some_name
layer.featureCount= -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're near the solution.

First, create data in Postgis :

```
CREATE SCHEMA test_data;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_data.test_satellite_boarders;
CREATE TABLE test_data.test_satellite_boarders (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50)
);

SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('test_data', 'test_satellite_boarders', 'geom', 4326, 'POINT', 2);

INSERT INTO test_data.test_satellite_boarders (name, geom)
SELECT 'pt1' AS name, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 9)', 4326) UNION ALL
SELECT 'pt1' AS name, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(2 8)', 4326) UNION ALL
SELECT 'pt1' AS name, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(3 7)', 4326) UNION ALL
SELECT 'pt1' AS name, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4 6)', 4326) UNION ALL
SELECT 'pt1' AS name, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 5)', 4326) UNION ALL
SELECT 'pt1' AS name, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(6 4)', 4326) UNION ALL
SELECT 'pt1' AS name, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(7 3)', 4326) UNION ALL
SELECT 'pt1' AS name, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(8 2)', 4326) UNION ALL
SELECT 'pt1' AS name, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(9 1)', 4326);
```

Secondly, fill parameters and correct a little the PyQGIS code :

```
def load_layer_from_DB(aSchema, aTable, aGeometryColumn, host, port, dbname, user, password):
    uri = qgis.core.QgsDataSourceUri()
    uri.setConnection(host, port, dbname, user, password)
    uri.setDataSource(aSchema, aTable, aGeometryColumn)
    layer = qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "some_name", "postgres")
    return layer

# connect stuff
dbname = "db_visdata"
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = "5432"
user = "postgres"
password = "admin"

# path in database
aSchema = "test_data"
aTable = "test_satellite_boarders"
aGeometryColumn = "geom"

layer = load_layer_from_DB(aSchema, aTable, aGeometryColumn, host, port, dbname, user, password)

print('layer.isValid=', layer.isValid())
print('layer.type=', layer.type())
print('layer.name=', layer.name())
print('layer.featureCount=', layer.featureCount())

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Errors :

1. `return layer` must be the last line for the function, if not, the function doesn't return the QgsVectorLayer object ;
2. the provider for a Postgis QgsVectorLayer is "postgres", [here the API doc](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.6/core/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=qgsvectorlayer) ;
3. the geometry column is the name of the geometry field. I didn't knwow if you made the error with `MultiPolygon` which is a geometry type, but I prefer to specify.
4. Bonus tip : if you use a view instead of a table, you'll have to specify the key column with `uri.setKeyColumn("id")`

Comment: Jesus! I was unable to add layer for a week because of this line: `aGeometryColumn = 'MultiPolygon'` instead of  `aGeometryColumn = "geom"`. God bless you and gis.stackexchange.com. All the documentation is broken or I am a blind.

Comment: The official documentation is here : https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers and it's working. So ...